# Is it possible to change Device's location?

Tags: root-access, gps, geolocation

I want to change my device location (lat,lang, etc) to a different place. I don't want to mock. I want it to function like If I open Google Maps, it points to my desired location not the real location.

Is it possible?
If yes, does it require root?

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: No mock locations? Requires root. Easiest would be any of the GPS spoofing apps using Xposed but there are many out there that only need root acess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do it if you have root access first you must Download the **FakeGPS** the link for the one i suggest is [Download Form Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.newapphorizons.fakegps&hl=en) and Change Location Mode to **Device Only(preferred)** and **turn on Mock Location from Developer options**
and set the location in the app this will spoof the GPS and its Working Fine !! :)